# Haskell Problem in all / map functions

Tags: haskell, dictionary

```
func::[Int]->Bool
func [] = False
func (l:ls) = ff1 (l)


ff1::Int->Bool
ff1 j = j > 0
```

Currently this code only matches the first value. I tryied using `map` and `all` but didn't get a good result.

My problem is that I need to check if all the values are matching the `ff1`'s pattern and if all the `ls list`  elements are **true** or **false**, returning a single boolean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just need `all`:

```
Prelude> :t all
all :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
Prelude> all (>0) [-10..10]
False
Prelude> all (>0) [1..10]
True
```

Or, if you want, you can do:

```
Prelude> let f1 x = x > 5 && x < 10
Prelude> let func xs = all f1 xs
Prelude> func [6..9]
True
Prelude> func [1..10]
False
```

which allows you to create a function `f1` to do a complex check. In any case, you can use `all` for your `func`

Comment: actually i have a complex pattern checking in `ff1 ` so this is not suitable :)

Comment: `all f1 xs` is the answer without parenthesis :-)

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
func ls = all ff1 ls
```

Or this:

```
func ls = and (map ff1 ls)
```

Comment: @Sudantha Can you give an example of input it doesn't work for, and the output that should be generated instead? Landei's answer should work for your question as I understand it, so perhaps we misunderstand your question. Could you expand it with example input and example output please?

Comment: Yes, I tried it out in GHCI, and it worked. Note that I edited the question, as `ff1 j > 0 = True` made no sense at all, and a `=`was missing in `func`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this -- assuming you wish to perform an "and" between all Bool results.

```
func::[Int]->Bool
func [] = True
func (l:ls) = ff1 (l) && func (ls)

ff1::Int->Bool
ff1 j = j > 0

main = do let a = func [-1, -2, 1, 2, 3]
          print a
```